# Is it possible to update camera position and lookdirection without using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I've got a WPF UserControl Library in Windows forms and I'm trying to update my camera position and lookdirection when event is triggered, but I want to do it without XAML. Is that even possible?
I have tried with:

```
userControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>
{
    userControl.UpdateCameraPOV();
});
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing any 3D work with .NET, the [Helix Toolkit](http://helix-toolkit.github.io/) is a great help. It includes a view control woth pan/tilt movement, and might be a good start for a view that you can control via code too.